# .NET Project build optimization on deployment to Azure

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, deployment, asp.net-web-api2

I "inherited" an already existing project that consists of a few Visual Studio projects inside a Visual Studio Solution, I have deployed to Azure before, but I didn't run into my current situation.

The project has a .NET WEB API 2 project that is already deployed on Azure, but I was asked to "separate" some components that are currently on that project into a separate API project (it's going to be deployed to another server in Azure).

The tree structure of the code repository is like this:

```
tree
.
├── invoice.read.api # --> web api
├── invoice.read.bll # --> business logic
├── invoice.read.core # --> core functions
├── invoice.read.dal # --> data access
└── invoice.read.sln # --> this is the VS solution file
```

So I have to take some of the functionality provided by invoice.read.core, and make a separate api, that's going to be deployed to another server in Azure, what I'd like to know is:

If I were to add a new API project to the Visual Studio Solution and mark it as the startup project for the deployment, will the deployment include everything on the Visual Studio Solution (even the unused projects)?

Or will Visual Studio deploy only what's used?

Basically, should I make a new solution, and migrate the code that's going to be in the separate API, or is that not necessary?

If there's any documentation on this subject you could point me to I'd be happy to read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely add a new API project to your existing solution. For the deployment purpose, you can right click on the project that you want to deploy, and then click on 'Publish'. It will only deploy that particular project and nothing else.

No need to create a new solution.

More information on publishing can be found here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx